# New Kivy installation: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require'

Tags: python, windows, kivy, spyder

kivy 1.10.0, python 3.4.5, windows 10, using Anaconda's Spyder IDE

After much trouble trying to install kivy on my windows 10 computer, I was able to...sort of. I downgraded python to the most recent supported version.

I put in kivy's stock code to make sure it's working:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Changing my version to 1.10.0. But I got the following error and trace back:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "<ipython-input-6-498c1728e978>", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/Programming/Kivvv/UsageExample.py',  wdir='C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/Programming/Kivvv')
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/Programming/Kivvv/UsageExample.py", line 12, in 
>       kivy.require('1.10.0') # replace with your current kivy version !
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require'

Also ran

```
print(dir(kivy))
```

which returned this list:

> ['**doc**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**']

My guess is that kivy didn't install properly, but I've had so many troubles installing it that I don't want to reinstalling it until that is clearly the next best option.

Also, if it helps, when running the kivy installation process on the kivy website, several steps return an error regarding "splitlines" even though each step successfully finishes--

> Exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>
> ```
> status = self.run(options, args)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
>
> ```
> wb.build(autobuilding=True)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
>
> ```
> self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
>
> ```
> ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
>
> ```
> check_dist_requires_python(dist)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
>
> ```
> feed_parser.feed(metadata)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 177, in feed
>
> ```
> self._input.push(data)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 100, in push
>
> ```
> parts = data.splitlines(True)
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Not sure if it make a difference, but I decided to include it in case it is a good clue to what's going on.

Thanks so much!!!

Update, 5-12-17:

I went ahead and tried the program by pasting it in notepad and running it from there, but I got the same error message.

I then did

```
python -m pip list
```

in the powershell, and none of these popped up:

```
Kivy (1.10.0)
Kivy-Garden (0.1.4)
kivy.deps.angle (0.1.4)
kivy.deps.glew (0.1.9)
kivy.deps.sdl2 (0.1.17)
```

It looks like kivy didn't install after all. After trying to run the installation again, here is what my computer shoots back at me:

```
PS C:\Users\Andrew> python -m pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-1.10.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 (from kivy)
  Using cached kivy-garden-0.1.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in 
c:\users\andrew\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from kivy)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in 
c:\users\andrew\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from kivy)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", 
line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 177, in feed
    self._input.push(data)
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 100, in push
    parts = data.splitlines(True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

Since I'm not getting that "kivy installed" message, it looks like this "splitlines" attribute error is preventing the installation from finishing. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with error, I just want to note that there's nothing hard in installing Kivy on Windows with any Python version. There's what you need to install Kivy as plain Python module: 1) Download whl file with version you want for your Python from https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/kivy/ 2) Use pip install your_filename_here.whl to install this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems more likely to me that your issue is with the ide. In fact if I was a betting man I'd bet everything I have that your IDE is the issue.

Please go through my answer and try the two scripts I posted. The most important thing you NEED to do now is paste the python code into notepad and run it through your command line.

If it works, you know what your issue is. If it doesn't try all the steps I've listed below. It's very possible that your ide is pointing to the wrong path(s) or something along those lines.

Try the following things please.

Step 1:

```
python -m pip list
```

Locate your kivy install and verify it's there, and it's version. You should see something like

```
Kivy (1.10.0)
Kivy-Garden (0.1.4)
kivy.deps.angle (0.1.4)
kivy.deps.glew (0.1.9)
kivy.deps.sdl2 (0.1.17)
```

If you see that stuff copy paste the below example and try running it.

Step 2: Script

```
import kivy


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

If you get the same errors.

Try the following 
    python -m pip show kivy

You should see something like

```
Name: Kivy
Version: 1.10.0
Summary: A software library for rapid development of hardware-accelerated 
multitouch applications.
Home-page: http://kivy.org
Author: Kivy Team and other contributors
Author-email: kivy-dev@googlegroups.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: pygments, Kivy-Garden, docutils
```

If you see this and even if you don't run the following command

```
python -m pip check kivy
```

This will tell you if you've met all the required dependencies for kivy. If not go through and install them.

There could be issues that I can't help you with based off of the current information that I have so my last piece of advice would be to do this as a last resort.

```
python -m pip uninstall kivy
python -m pip install kivy==1.10.0
```

Update: 
I've never used power shell so I don't know how it operates. Try using the command promot. Also you're using Anacondas IDE but are you also using Anaconda Python? If so certain commands are different and you'd have to bypass it and use the official tools. To make sure it's not a compatibility  issue. https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq

From what I see in the error code your kivy install is there and fine. Which means it's directly related to spider.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to send a pm in stackoverflow, but I did update my question. See above. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq I mean I personally don't like this I prefer official Python. With that said you'll need to setup a path to your bundled Python install and run it.  Also I've never actually used the power shell so I can't say if any of that will work in it though I assume it would.  The issue is with your ide so you need to try and determine if you can run your code without using it . Check that link to locate the commands and try using cmd not power shell.

Answer (score 2):

It's showing error because of the File name you are saving the file with name 'kivy.py' which inturn is contradicting with kivy core package. Try renaming the file Hope it helps.