# Although I have pip installed and import kivy in cmd, I still get an error and the code is not executed

Tags: python, android, visual-studio-2010, pip, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HYPER\Desktop\training.py\from kivy.app import App.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "c:\Users\HYPER\Desktop\training.py\kivy.py", line 2, in <module>
    kivy.require('1.9.0')`enter code here`
AttributeError: module 'kivy' has no attribute 'require'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 4.102 seconds
```

Comment: What happens if you try to run this code in the Python interpreter? It's working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Again it gives the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New Kivy installation: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896924/new-kivy-installation-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-require)

Comment: In IDLE Python it gives me the answer : SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement